# Changing a form html name in a template

Tags: python, django

I'm looking at a package called [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) I was wondering if it was possible to change the html name from within the template?

i.e.

```
{{ form.username|changename }}
```

Rules:

I don't want to change the original form or view (at all), I only have access to the template.

Comment: if you change the `id` of the field, it won't match anymore when you post. if you want to change the `label`, you can do that in your form.py file. so please, be more specific, what's `name` for you? also, you're changing a field there, not a form name.

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo sorry yes its the label I want to change, however as stated I don't want to change this in the form.py due to it being a packaging also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're changing the label, I suggest you do it template-ish, without using a templatetag or a filter:

```
<label for="id_username">Your label name here:</label>
{{ form.username }}
```

Or, if you can't resist, you have to apply a filter to your `field.label` property:

```
{{ form.username.label|my_custom_filter }}
```

A simple filter could be:

```
@register.filter(name='my_custom_filter')
def my_custom_filter(value):
    # here value is the value of your label
    # process it as you please then return the new value
    if value == 'changeme':
        return 'changed label'
    return value
```

This is just an example to show you how a template filter works, you have then to elaborate it and change name, logic etc etc

Answer (score 1):

This could be over simplifying it, but what not just raw output it?

```
<label for="">what ever you want</label>
<input type="text" name="{{ form.username.html_name }}" id="{{ form.username.auto_id }}">
```

I would still do this in the form.py myself but if all you have is the template to work with then it does not need anything fancy here.